# Extreme memory usage by TensorFlow and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm training a convoluted neural network, and my code behaves very differently depending on whether I comment out this single line:

```
print("validation accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: validation_predictors, y_: validation_targets, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

When this line is commented out, TensorFlow is very smooth and consumes about 8 GB. When this line is not commented out, TensorFlow consumes all of the memory on my entire system, and SIGKILL terminates the process with a 137 return code (out of memory error). My train dataset is 32620 records, and my validation dataset (the one that leads to the error) is only 5292 records.

I'm using TensorFlow (0.9.0) and numpy (1.11.1) with Python 3.4.4. I have a 2.5 GB dataset. I'm running OSX Yosemite 10.10, and I've got a 16 GB of ram on my machine.

Why does this tiny validation dataset blowing up my machine and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: is that the first `eval` statement in your code?

Comment: I think you try to feed the whole validation set to Tensorflow, whereas you should divide it in smaller batches

Comment: @James Yes, that's the eval statement. To be honest, I'm not really sure how the eval statement works. I pulled it from one of the TensorFlow tutorials: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot I figured it would be ok to feed the whole validation set into TensorFlow because my machine has 16 GB of ram and the validation set is only about 300 MB. I definitely didn't expect the 300 MB to blow up

Comment: Tensorflow builds a graph of operations and dataflows.  But nothing is actually evaluated until you ask for it.  Calling `eval` essentially asks tensorflow to do all of the operations up to that point in the graph and then spit out some text.  The 8Gb of memory usage is the backbone structure you have set up.  The memory overflow occurs when you actually ask it to do the processing.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    testSet = mnist.test.next_batch(500)
    print("test accuracy %g" % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: testSet[0], y_: testSet[1], keep_prob: 1.0}))
```